# Dynamic TextEditor overlapping with other views

Tags: swift, swiftui, text-editor, geometryreader

So I have made a successful dynamic TextEditor but when I try to combine views, it overlaps the other elements and no longer expands as you type. I am pretty sure this has to do with Geometry Reader but I am not sure how to do it without that. Thanks!

```
ScrollView {
    
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        
        
        VStack{
            
            
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                Text(text).foregroundColor(.clear)
                .padding(14)
                .font(.custom("Times", size: 14))
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: viewheightkey3.self, value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                })
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.9)
                
                TextEditor(text: $text)
                .padding(6)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.9)
                .frame(height: height)
                .frame(minHeight: 100)
                .background(Color.black)
                
            }
            
            .padding(20)
            .onPreferenceChange(viewheightkey3.self) { height = $0 }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    struct viewheightkey3: PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
        static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
            value = value + nextValue()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can stand to get rid of the frame width stuff (which you can probably substitute with just doing some horizontal padding), this seems to work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textEditorHeight : CGFloat = 100
    @State private var text = "Testing text. Hit a few returns to see what happens"
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
                Text("This should be above")
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(text)
                        .font(.custom("Courier", size: 24))
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .padding(14)
                        .background(GeometryReader {
                            Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                                   value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                        })
                    
                    TextEditor(text: $text)
                        .font(.custom("Courier", size: 24))
                        .padding(6)
                        .frame(height: textEditorHeight)
                        .background(Color.black)
                }
                .padding(20)
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { textEditorHeight = $0 }
                
                Text("This should be below the text field")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = value + nextValue()
    }
}
```

I didn't really change anything fundamental to what you did. Mostly just got rid of the outside `GeometryReader` and made the `frame` dependent *only* on the height being passed in from the `PreferenceKey`

Comment: Hi! Any insight onto why this stops working when I change the font size? I change it for both the TextEditor and the text and I've tried changing padding and multiplying/adding to the textEditorHeight

Comment: I can't replicate that on my end (at least on iOS 14.4). Just updated my answer with code that changes the font size and works fine

Comment: hm. It works... unless I use Times font. I can obviously use something else but it is bizarre

Comment: update: you have to specify line spacing for Times

Comment: Yes I forgot! I will note for future readers that deleting .frame(height: textEditorHeight) from the TextEditor and adding a max/min padding to Text will allow you to set parameters on the size